# Angular HighChart in tabs width

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, highcharts, tabs

Okay so i have the following highChart tag:

```
<highchart id="chart1" config="chartConfig" ></highchart>
```

Now in my system i have several tabs. it happens to be that the high chart is not under the first tab.

[image]

Now when i press the tab that contains the chart, the chart looks abit odd:

[image]

(You can't tell from this picture but it is only using like 30% of the total width)

But change the browser size and then changing it back to normal the chart places it self correctly inside the element (this also happens if i just open the console while i am inside the tab):

[image]

I am guessing  that it has something to do with the width of the element once it has been created (maybe because it is within another tab) but i am unsure how to fix this.

I attempted to put a style on the element containg the highchart so that it would look something like this: `<highchart id="chart1" config="chartConfig style="width: 100%"></highchart>`

However this resulted in the chart running out of the frame.

**My chart config**

```
    $scope.chartConfig = {
};

$scope.$watchGroup(['login_data'], function(newValues, oldValues) {

    // newValues[0] --> $scope.line
    // newValues[1] --> $scope.bar

    if(newValues !== oldValues) {
        $scope.chartConfig = {
            options: {
                chart: {
                    type: 'areaspline'
                }
            },
            series: [{
                data: $scope.login_data,
                type: 'line',
                name: 'Aktivitet'
            }],
            xAxis: {
                categories: $scope.login_ticks
            },
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            loading: false
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: `However if i attempt to just quickly making the browser smaller and then back to full size the chart is correctly placed within the page` I'm not clear on what you are saying here. Can you please reword?

Comment: Also can you post your chart config?

Comment: Not sure what the issue is, but try using the `size` config option.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg David in short the problem is that on page load the chart is about 30% of the element width but it stabilizes as soon as i do something to the browser window

Comment: What I meant to say was that I get the issue, I just have no clue how to fix it :)

Comment: Have you tried to call [reflow](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.reflow)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try one of the following in your controller?  (or perhaps both!)

```
$timeout(function() {
    $scope.chartConfig.redraw();
});

$timeout(function() {
    $scope.chartConfig.setSize();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling the **reflow** method solved my similar issue on showing chart in a modal. Hope this will help others :D

Add this to your controller after **$scope.chartConfig**:

```
$scope.reflow = function () {
  $scope.$broadcast('highchartsng.reflow');
};
```